# State always shows initial value inside a listener function of third party package [React]

Tags: reactjs

**Problem**: Whenever the listener function is executed when a new message is received, I want to add the new message (just an object), into a state variable `messages`. But the state variable is always in its initial state (i.e. empty list), even after the 2nd or 3rd messages.

**Intended outcome:**
Upon receiving a message, `connection.onstream` will be invoked, and add the new message into a state variable `messages` using `setMessages`.

```js
const Messager = ( ) => {
  let [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  var connection = new ThirdPartyMessager();

  connection.onstream = function (event) { // when recieve a message, this will be called

    console.log(messages); // problem, this always shows initial state, i.e. []

    setMessages([ // thus setmessage will always have 1 item after adding new message
      ...messages,
      event.message
    ]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages` in `connection.onstream` is initial with `[]` when you listen on stream and the `connection.onstream` continuously lives while you call `setMessages` ==> `messages` is always `[]`, it's closure concept of JS.
You can try this to fix your issue:

```
 setMessages(prevMessages = > ([...prevMessages,event.message]));
```

Updated: [This is a good example from React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often) about setting state on a event `setInterval` in there case, but it works for events `onstream` in your case.

Comment: I am glad it helped. I also add a link which is a sample code about setting state inside an event . It might help, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using an Effect

```
const Messager = () => {
  let [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  var connection = new ThirdPartyMessager();

  useEffect(() => {
    connection.onstream = function (event) {
      console.log(messages);
      setMessages([
        ...messages,
        event.message,
      ]);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: We have to remove `[]` from useEffect dependency otherwise this won't work as dependency is set to `[]` which means this will only run for the first time after that there is nothing that will cause setMessage to triggger. Thus, code inside useEffect will never apply after first render which is exactly the problem OP has in first place. Thus, we can  take out `[]` from useEffect and let it run always which should work as expected.